# Different URL rewrite rules loading the same page

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a custom post type and building a URL based on parameters I'm passing through a query_vars filter, but both of these rules are loading the same page from my child theme:

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $feed_rules = array(
        '([^/]+)/series/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'crossroads-sermons/'.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(3).'&series='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&campus='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
        '([^/]+)/series/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?series='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&campus='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

The url is rewriting correctly in the address bar of the browser, but it loads the same page layout as the second rule. Any ideas why the first rule isn't loading the right template, even though going to /crossroads-sermons/name-of-the-sermon/ works perfectly?